# parallel processing in perl. CPU usage 100%

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, cpu-usage

i have developed a script for data extraction in perl.

using a `parallel::ForkManager` module and its functionalities

it works well when i run the script from 4core cpu.
but when i try to run it from different cpu which is of 2core only has a cpu usage 100%.

my problem is to reduce that cpu usage n run script smoothly.
i already reduces the max_Child_process to 10 previously it was 40.
restriction:  my script must parse all pages and store data in database  within a 25 seconds.
currently it is doing it in 22-24 seconds but uses full cpu. can anybody gives me some idea about how and what to do for reducing my cpu usage.

Comment: Just a guess. Your Perl script is busy preparing and sending data to database, waiting for response and use a lot of CPU while actually does little computing.  Loading large data usually requires special batch programming. You can try use Perl to format your data to CSV or tsv format and use database's own bulk loading tool to insert the data.

Comment: Reducing CPU usage is easy: Add `sleep` statements. That's really odd, though. Most people want their programs to run faster.

Comment: I think you should show us your code

Comment: Tim3880 thanks i will look in this direction .. may be a solution it is..

Answer (score 0):

Use a usleep when waiting for child processes.

`until (waitpid(-1, WNOHANG)) {
   usleep(100);
}`

Dramatically reduces cpu in parallel programs